# Seleniumchrome driver cannot open

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to just open Google website from my java class to test selenium.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "********\\chromedriver.exe");
// Create an instance of the driver

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

> Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}) on port 36521. Only local connections are allowed.
>
> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to write automation extension zip
>
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>
> System info: host: 'USLOSULA91634G5', ip: '10.18.71.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: It is probably outdated driver or "********\\chromedriver.exe" is incorrect path

Comment: possibly a permissions issue.  Are you able to launch Chrome manually?

Comment: Yes, manually, it works just fine.

Comment: Try download latest version of selenium driver here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads. And by the way, you sure your chromedriver was unziped?

Comment: i have the latest sel driver and yes, chromedriver is unzipped

Comment: Maybe blind shot, use Java version 1.8.0_15X or higher.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, i had lot of security restrictions on my computer.I had to place the selenium webdriver.exe in a folder where i had full access to it. 
Thanks to everyone who tried.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue,

I am using Linux Machine, my chrome version is 90.x and the dependency present in my POM is:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have cleared the .m2 folder, and installed and uninstall the various version of chrome and eclipse combinations but still while executing the selenium scripts every time it is pointing to 93.x version of chrome, which is actually not present in the system.

But the same scripts are working fine on another linux machine. I can assume it could me platform related issue, but can't able to identify what could be the solution.

```
              WebDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.CHROME).setup();
                downloadfolder = new File(upload_contractfile_path);
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//              options.addArguments("headless");
                options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
                options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
                options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
                prefs.put("download.default_directory", 
                downloadfolder.getAbsolutePath());
                options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
                DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```